# codeigniter : How to store product selection in the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my shopping cart. There are products that have 2 types of options that have been selected. Namely color and size. How to save to database?

my controller :

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item)
{
    if(empty($items['before']))
    {
        $harga_fix_diskon_atau_non_diskon = $this->cart->format_number($item['price']);
    }
    else
    {
        $harga_fix_diskon_atau_non_diskon = $this->cart->format_number($item['before']);
    }
    foreach ($this->cart->product_options($item['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value)
    {
        if(empty($option_value))
        {
            $option_value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $option_value;
        }
        $option = $option_value;
    }
    $data_order[] = array(
        'invoice'     => $invoice,
        'name_product' => $item['name'],
        'size'        => $item['option'],
        'color'       => $item['option'],
        'qty'         => $item['qty'],
        'price'       => $harga_fix_diskon_atau_non_diskon,
        'weight'      => $item['berat'],
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('order_product', $data_order);
```

I have saved all the data except in the product selection section

The result of my database process is a matter of size and color :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| invoice | name_product | size | color | qty | price | weight |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| ST5623  | Nike         |  42  | 42    |  2  |   28  |  0,5   |
```

*Should be in color columns containing **colors.**

If i use print_r (); And managed to show me what I wanted. Namely the color is color and size is size

```
foreach ($this->cart->product_options($item['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value)
{
    if(empty($option_value))
    {
        $option_value = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $option_value;
    }
    $option = $option_value;
    print_r($option);
}
```

please for help. thank you.

Comment: you need to update the color and size column based on select isn't it ?

Comment: yes sir........

Comment: just use $this->db->update()

Comment: On the color part and size is not updated properly. See result from my database. Color column filled by shoe number. Should not be so

Comment: because your setting same value for color and size 'size'        => $item['option'],
              'color'       => $item['option'],  @Danny Setyawan

Comment: How the code should be?

Comment: 'color' => $user_selected_color_variable

Comment: imho your code doesn't make any sense - especially the nested foreach options part. Usually are sizes and colors product options (sku) - print out your cart here with 1 sample item and 2 options

Answer (score 0):

because your setting same value for color and size

```
'size' => $item['option'], 'color' => $item['option']
```

Or you need to check  $item for color parameter